# View Controller will not appear when Table View Controller Cell is Selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I am relatively new to Swift/Xcode and I am trying to make a view controller appear with different values when a button is selected (an add button) or a table view cell is selected (which allows them to edit). However, I am unable to get any response upon the selection of my row including a print statement I have put in for testing, although the segue does function when I link the transition to a button. The code is identical to that of a functioning table view cell I wrote previously that makes the current table view appear. Could this be an issue with the storyboard?

[Storyboard screenshot with cell settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcFYl.png)

Here is my code:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Selected")
}

//Sends current receipt information to the AddItemViewController display when tapped
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddItemViewSegue" || segue.identifier == "EditItemViewSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as? AddItemViewController
        destination?.currentReceipt = currentReceipt
        let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        print("test")
        if segue.identifier == "AddItemViewSegue" {
            destination?.addMessage = "Add a New Item to Your Receipt"
            destination?.buttonMessage = "Add Item"
        }
        else {
            print("test1")
            destination?.addMessage = "Edit an Item in Your Receipt"
            destination?.buttonMessage = "Edit Item"
            destination?.currentItem = items[index!]
        }
    }
}
```

I have also looked into this forum post because it is similar to mine but I was unable to apply any of the suggested fixes.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/14842

Comment: if you use didselectRow you need to use performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: Have you tried implement delegate height for cell ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `didSelectRow` method is wrong. The code is Swift 2 code. The proper signature is

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { ...
```

Didn't you wonder why the compiler doesn't complain about the missing `override`?

Rather than from the view controller reconnect the segue (why are there 2 ones?) from the table view **cell** to the destination controller and delete `didSelectRow`